# gghighlight highlighting lines with certain labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, data-visualization, gghighlight

I am trying to build a time-series plot and highlight certain lines based on the country that line belongs to. However, I couldn't find a way to highlight based on label names. I tried the following code, and although it worked, it also raised an error.

```
graph <- final_data %>%
  filter(X %in% country_names) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year,
             y=obesity_proportions,
             colour=X)) +
  geom_line() + 
  gghighlight(X == "United States of America",
              label_key = X) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Here is the output graph:

[The output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrxss.png)

However, it also raised an error with this graph.
Here is the error code:

```
Warning message:
Tried to calculate with group_by(), but the calculation failed.
Falling back to ungrouped filter operation...
```

How can I fix this error and is there a better way to highlight by country?

Comment: That is not an error but a warning. It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: The predict needs to return a single value per group if you want to choose the series to highlight in a group-wise manner. Expressions like `all(X == "United Stats of America")` should work.